# How to use ImportXML in Google Sheets to import attribute of html-tag?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given is a webpage with this source code:

```
<table style="border-top:solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right:solid 1px #C0C0C0;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <colgroup>
  <col width="25%">
  <col width="25%">
  <col width="25%">
  <col width="25%">
 </colgroup>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  </tr><tr>
   <td class="fvtEntete3"><b>Trade Rating : </b></td>
   <td class="fvtCorps1" title="22%"><span title="22%" class="spr0 spr_star1"> </span></td>
   <td class="fvtEntete3"><b>Investment Rating : </b></td>
   <td class="fvtCorps1" title="11%"><span title="11%" class="spr0 spr_star0_5"> </span>       </td>
  </tr>    
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

I want to extract the title attributes to GoogleSheets.
In this example i want to get "11%" and "22%".
But these values are variable and change from site to site.

Is this possible with ImportXML-function?

Comment: Are the two target values always in a `<td>` with a `class="fvtCorps1`, always after "Trade Rating" and "Investment Rating" or something else? In short, what distinguishes their position in the html?

Comment: yes, the target values are always at the same position with the same html-tag and class. Unfortunately they use the same `class="fvtCorps1"` so probably i have to put the result in an array or something...

Comment: i was able to get everything what's inside the (unique) table with this:
`=Trim(REGEXREPLACE(iferror(INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.example-url.com";"//table[contains(@style,'border-top:solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right:solid 1px #C0C0C0;')]//@*");1;2));">"))"))"`. But I don't know how to get only `"22%"` or `"11%"`.

Comment: whats the url??

Answer (score 2):

In importXML function, use this xpath expression

```
//td[b[.="Trade Rating : "]]/following-sibling::td[1]/data(@title)
```

to output `22%` and

```
//td[b[.="Investment Rating : "]]/following-sibling::td[1]/data(@title)
```

to output `11%`.

Comment: XPaths returns errors. data(@title) should be @title, right ? Otherwise, shorter but riskier : `//td[@class="fvtCorps1"]/@title`